# Syntax error with preg_replace (novice user)

Tags: php

I have the code below which begins extraction of data from my DB, I want to insert the function below to work in the "product description"

```
echo '<Product>
        <ID><![CDATA['.$row['ID'].']]></ID>
        <ProductName><![CDATA['.htmlspecialchars_decode($row['ProductName']).']]></ProductName>
        <ProductCode><![CDATA['.$row['ProductCode'].']]></ProductCode>
        <Category><![CDATA['.$row['Category'].' > '.$row['Category_sub_1'].']]></Category>
        <Price><![CDATA['.$row['Price'].']]></Price>
        <MarketPrice><![CDATA['.$row['MarketPrice'].']]></MarketPrice>
        <AvailableQty><![CDATA['.$row['AvailableQty'].']]></AvailableQty>
        <Condition><![CDATA['.$row['Condition_new'].']]></Condition>
        <Weight><![CDATA['.$row['Weight'].']]></Weight>
        <ShippingProductClass><![CDATA['.$row['ShippingProductClass'].']]></ShippingProductClass>
        <ImageURL><![CDATA['.$row['ImageURL'].']]></ImageURL>
        <ProductDescription><![CDATA['.htmlspecialchars_decode($row['ProductDescription']).']]></ProductDescription>
        </Product>
        ';
}}}
```

Where do I place :

```
function swearwords($word){
    $word = preg_replace('/\b(w{3,4}\.)*(?<!img\.|imgmgr\.)badword(\.com)*\b/iu', '', $word);
    return $word;
}
```

Comment: So, call the function on `$row['ProductDescription']`? Like `swearwords($row['ProductDescription']);`.

Comment: really sorry, I did mention novice , [CDATA['.htmlspecialchars_decode:swearwords($row['ProductDescription']).']]></ProductDescription>